# phpinfo says php.ini path is C:\Windows but there is no php.ini there

Tags: php, apache

We are trying to switch from PHP5 to PHP7.

We now have Apache installed and PHP works.

However, the changes we made in the `php.ini` file have no effect.

Via `phpinfo()` we realized the reason is that the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` is `C:\Windows`.

In our `httpd.conf` we have:

```
# PHP7 setup
LoadFile "C:/test/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/test/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler php7-script .php
PHPINIDir "C:/test/php"
```

Which I understand is supposed to make Apache look for the `php.ini` in `c:\test\php` (forward slashes are used in the http.conf as is required)

Not understanding why Apache doesn't look for `php.ini` where we tell it to, we put the `php.ini` in `c:\Windows` where it still is not read (the modules which we load in the `php.ini` are not loaded in phpinfo).

Each time we make changes to `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`, we restart Apache with the Apache monitor.

**How can we tell Apache to read the `php.ini` file in a specific directory other than what we have tried above?**

## Addendum:

[image]

We switched everything back to PHP5 and now get the same error as in the above screenshot for where the PHP path is. It says it is now PHP 5.6.0 so it is obviously loading the new PHP version but something has changed so that the php.ini file is not read in either version. (???)

A reboot doesn't help either.

Comment: may be this will be helpful https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Comment: try using PHPRC? you can  specify the path to the directory containing your php.ini, not the direct path to the php.ini. So **export PHPRC=/test/php** . Hope this helps?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a caching issue when executing the `phpinfo()` script... Make sure to make a deep reload in your browser or to disable your cache for that.

Comment: Look at the line below (**Loaded Configuration File**). The *Configuration File (php.ini) Path* has shown *C:\Windows* for years for no obvious reason.

Comment: is ;c:\php added to the PATH? at System Variables

Comment: baboizk, my Windows environment system variable string includes `C:\test\php` if that is what you mean.

Comment: arkascha, deep reloading (SHIFT-F5 and CTRL-F5) doesn't bring any change

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything wrong with your php.ini settings. I can read "test"... Do you have another PHP installation in the same machine that might be interferring, such as PHP/5.x?

Comment: Álvaro, if I stop the Apache server, I get "unable to connect" when trying to load the page as expected. There are no other Apache or PHP installations on this machine that I know of, it's a dev machine and so nothing is installed that I haven't installed.

Comment: Just for the sake of being fully sure... Can you try the exact directives shown in the PHP documentation (`SetHandler` instead of `AddHandler`, etc.)? As last resort, I might suggest [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). I've used it in the past to diagnose installation of PHP extensions.

Answer (score 4):

You can try add trailing slash

```
PHPINIDir "C:/test/php/"
```

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php)

> **Note**: Remember that when adding path values in the Apache configuration files on Windows, all backslashes such as
>   c:\directory\file.ext should be converted to forward slashes:
>   c:/directory/file.ext. A trailing slash may also be necessary for
>   directories.

Comment: Interesting remark about trailing slash... I've never used it and even the example on that same page doesn't use either... But with PHP and Windows you never know.

Comment: I tried `PHPIniDir "C:/test/php/"` and `PHPINIDir "C:/test/php/"` but to no avail. It's as if it is just ignoring this line. If I take out any other line, e.g. `LoadFile "C:/test/php/php5ts.dll"` or `LoadModule php5_module "C:/test/php/php5apache2_4.dll"` then PHP stops working, so I know Apache is parsing these lines, it is just ignoring the `PHPINIDir` line for some reason it seems.

Comment: And there is no mention of PHP anywhere else in the `httpd.conf` file, e.g. no other settings which override these.