# my_phpinfo.php is blank after adding php.ini file

Tags: php, server, configuration, config, ini

I installed php and started the server at localhost:4000. The root is ~ i.e PC name. I created my_phpinfo.php file there to see configuration. It has phpinfo() function within php tags. When I loaded the file in Chrome, it's not showing configuration file address. The place (next to "Loaded Configuration File") where the address should be says "None" . The configuration file path for php.ini (as per my_phpinfo.php) is "C:/Windows" but there is no php.ini file there. After browsing a bit, I found that the file should be in C/PHP folder. But instead of it, there are "php.ini-development" and "php.ini-production" files. So i copied "php.ini-development" and pasted it in C/Windows, renamed it to php.ini. But after that localhost:4000/my_phpinfo.php turns blank. Where can i get the actual  php.ini file and why is the value for "Loaded Configuration File"set to "none". [error image](https://yogeshsportfolio.com/)

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936745/phpinfo-says-php-ini-path-is-c-windows-but-there-is-no-php-ini-there helps.

Comment: i don't seem to understand much of the comments there, maybe i'll have to learn about how server work